# Custom class Autoloading and global use zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have created custom PHP class that contains useful functions I need to use them in my zf2 project, and I want to be auto-loaded and to be used in all controllers and models (GLOBAL) is that possible? and how? 
I did the following:
/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php

```
return array(
    'Libs\\' => array($vendorDir . '/classes/lib'),
    'Zend\\' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
```

I call it in IndexController.php

```
use Libs\Myclass;
```

in My Custom class:
/vendor/classes/lib/Libs/Myclass.php

```
namespace Libs;

class Myclass {
   --
}
```

is this right?? and is this global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct editing `autoload_namespaces.php` file is bad practice.
You should add additional autoload configuration into composer.json file.
For your case is:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Libs": "vendor/classes/lib/"
    }
}
```

Nonetheless, if you intend to edit `autoload_namespaces.php` directly, then autoload of `Libs` namespace should be:

```
'Libs' => array($vendorDir . '/classes/lib'),
```